# How to gather same keys from multidimensional array and store in new array

Tags: php, arrays

**Problem**
I'd like to gather all similar Keys in a multidimensional array and store them in a new array. Here's the array:

```
$terms = Array ( 
    [1] => stdClass Object ( 
        [name] => Plumbing 
        [slug] => plumbing 
        [term_group] => 0 
    ) 
    [2] => stdClass Object ( 
        [name] => Test 
        [slug] => test 
        [term_group] => 0 
    ) 
)
```

And I'd like to make an array that contains only the [slug] keys.

**Attempt at Solution Using Above Array**

```
function gatherSameKeys($array, $key) {
    $result = array();
    foreach($array as $sub) {
        $result[] = $sub[$key];
    }
    return $result;
}
?>

<?php $newarray = gatherSameKeys($terms, 'slug'); ?>


<pre>
    <?php
        print_r ($newarray);
    ?>
</pre>
```

Comment: `$terms` is an array of objects, not arrays. Try `$sub->$key` instead of `$sub[$key]`.

Comment: For that you should convert your stdClass to array. just use c-style casting for that. I.e: $result[] = (array)$sub[$key];

Comment: You should actually do a recursive function for that. Then it would be able to get the keys from unlimited levels. Other solution would be to use array_walk_recursive function.

Comment: @andy Ahhhh thank you! I had no idea an array of objects acts differently than an array of arrays.

Answer (score 0):

According to your dump, `$terms` is an array of objects, not arrays.

To access a property of an object, use `$sub-&gt;$key` instead of `$sub[$key]`.